# Force Firestore Database to Cache Database

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to force the Firestore Database to cache an entire database offline?
Currently, Firestore caches what has already been accessed in the app.  I want to use data offline that the user may not have accessed before going offline.

I'm using Flutter for the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to locally cache data from Firestore is to actually query for that data.  You will need to execute queries for all the documents you wish to cache.  There is currently no alternative to this.